# Play! templates - passing dynamic string to javascript doesn't work?

Tags: java, javascript, groovy, playframework

Basically, in the controller, something dynamic happens, and I pass a non-static string to the view:

```
String token = "";
render(token);
```

I can easily do:

```
<div id="token>${token}</div>
```

...and grab the contents:

```
$('#token').html();
```

But what doesn't seem to work is, in the javascript, doing:

```
function token(token) {
  // do something with token
  console.log('token: ' + token);
}

token(${token});
```

I can kind of see why it doesn't work...but what is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You didn't name your function.  It should be:</strike>

```
function token(token) {
  // do something with token
  console.log('token: ' + token);
}
token(${token});
```

**Edit:** You may need to just add quotes:

```
token("${token}");
```

By the way, this works, but in general I'd avoid using the same name for the function and its argument.  A better name might be `logToken`:

```
function logToken(token) {
  // do something with token
  console.log('token: ' + token);
}

logToken("${token}");
```

Comment: @Frank - In that case, you probably are just missing quotes.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: token: ${token} is what that gives me..which I definitely tried before :)

Comment: @Frank - When you use `token(${token})` and view source, I suspect you will find that `${token}` is being written literally and is not being parsed.  I'm not familiar with Play Framework, so I can't provide much guidance on that front.  But just to guess, is this in an external .js file?  Are other Play tags in the same source file being parsed correctly?

Comment: Good guess :)  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/SkzYNlAjyyo/discussion